# Member since date string with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating author pages for a wordpress site I am working on, and I would like to display the member since date. Is there a string that can get the user data based on what author is being displayed and echo it out on screen?

I did some research, but most articles on this topic only echo the date for a user that is currently logged in. I want the date displayed even for people just viewing the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use something like this:

```
$AuthorData = get_user_by( 'slug', 'user_slug' );
$Date = $AuthorData->user_registered;
echo $Date ."<br /><br />";
```

Can use also  `id`, `email` or `login` instead of `slug`

Comment: I actually figured this out on my own based on some of the code you provided me with. I was looking for the `user_registered` string.  For those of you who may need the same solution, if you already set the `$curauth` variable, you can just enter `<?php echo $curauth->user_registered; ?>`

Comment: Glad my answer was useful.